# Python 3 pyOpenGL install problems

Tags: python, pyopengl

So I'm attempting to install pyOpenGL to work on some projects and gain a deeper understanding of python stuff..But I'm coming into contact with the **error** I posted here. To me it seems like a folder hierarchy issue but I suck at fixing those. I tried updating setuptools and installing the openGL context separate but to no avail...I have Python 3 downloaded directly into my c: drive because my python 2.7 was in appdata and was annoying to work with...But now I'm thinking my pip install is referring to that because it looks like that in my **error**..

But..I have no clue..

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Complete output from command c:\python3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\KODY~1.DES\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-do61jv87\pyOpenGL-accelerate\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\KODY~1.DES\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-sgf63oun-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Unable to import numpy, skipping numpy extension building
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\OpenGL_accelerate
    copying .\setup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\OpenGL_accelerate
    copying .__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\OpenGL_accelerate
    running build_ext
    building 'OpenGL_accelerate.wrapper' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.5
    creating build\temp.win32-3.5\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\src
    cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\KODY~1.DES\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-do61jv87\pyOpenGL-accelerate.. -IC:\Users\KODY~1.DES\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-do61jv87\pyOpenGL-accelerate\src -IC:\Users\KODY~1.DES\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-do61jv87\pyOpenGL-accelerate -Ic:\python3\include -Ic:\python3\include /Tcsrc\wrapper.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.5\Release\src\wrapper.obj
    error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory

```
----------------------------------------
```

Command "c:\python3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\KODY~1.DES\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-do61jv87\pyOpenGL-accelerate\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\KODY~1.DES\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-sgf63oun-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\KODY~1.DES\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-do61jv87\pyOpenGL-accelerate\

Comment: I think the formatting with your error code got messed up there, but have you tried installing PyOpenGL via pip? All I did to install it in windows was: `python -m pip install PyOpenGL`.

Comment: That was the error I received when I tried to download via powershell. what did you download it through?

Comment: I just downloaded it through the Windows command prompt by running the command I had in the previous comment. That was for python2 though, but I don't think it would change for python3 too dramatically.

Comment: tried there 2...hmmm

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue make sure you have the latest version of Microsoft Visual C++ before installing PyOpenGL_accelerate

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/